# why summ1 is not getting printed even it is defined in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,m1,m2):
        self.m1=m1
        self.m2=m2

    def add(self,s1,s2):
        summ1 = self.m1 + self.m2
        summ2 = s1.m1 + s1.m2
        summ3 = s2.m1 + s2.m2

std1=Student(89,99)
std2=Student(95,99)
std3=Student(95,99)
std1.add(std2,std3)

print(summ1)
print(summ2)
print(summ3)
```

**why summ1 is not getting printed even it is defined in function?**
Well summ1,summ2,summ3 are defined in add function when I try to print them this code is giving me error.

**Error is**
NameError: name 'summ1' is not defined

Comment: You are not storing `summ1..3` anywhere; they are within local scope of `add` method. You can't access them outside that method. You can try to do `self.summ1 = summ1` to make it an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`summ1`,`summ2`,`summ3` are local variables defined in the function `add` and they are not visible outside of this function. If you replace them by `self.summ1`, `self.summ2`, `self.summ3`, then `print(std1.summ1)` etc. will work.

Answer (score 0):

As AnkurSaxena said, you can not access your variables the way you try it.

The following code should solve your problem:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,m1,m2):
        self.m1=m1
        self.m2=m2
        self.summ1 = None
        self.summ2 = None
        self.summ3 = None

    def add(self,s1,s2):
        self.summ1 = self.m1 + self.m2
        self.summ2 = s1.m1 + s1.m2
        self.summ3 = s2.m1 + s2.m2

std1=Student(89,99)
std2=Student(95,99)
std3=Student(95,99)
std1.add(std2,std3)

print(std1.summ1)
print(std1.summ2)
print(std1.summ3)
```